# Include or exclude JSON data if the value is empty WITHOUT using multiple If statements

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON to send via python requests.  There are about 200 separate items.  I want to set each item in the JSON to a variable and if the variable is empty I want to exclude the item from the list.  How can I do this efficiently?  I could put a ton of IF statements in, but I don't think that's very efficient.

```
#The variables:
_var1 = 123
_var2 = 40
_var3 = ""
_var4 = 5

#The JSON:
"""
{
  "id": _var1,
  "weight": _var2,
  "width": _var3,
  "depth": _var4
  }
"""

#My desired result:
"""
{
  "id": _var1,
  "weight": _var2,
  "depth": _var4
  }
"""
```

I assume I could could use multiple if/else statements.  and then concatenate all of the strings.

```
if len(_var1)>0:
    print(str(_var11))
else: print("")
if len(_var2)>0:
    print(str(_var2))
else: print("")
```

I'm also assuming someone has a better way.  I don't really want to write 200 if/else statements.

Comment: `_var1` is a number, it doesn't have a length. And what does the JSON have to do with this? You're just printing variables.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to create JSON. Create a dictionary, then use `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single if clause to check if it's empty

```py
import json
keys = ["id", "weight", "width", "depth"]
vals = [_var1, _var2, _var3, _var4]

# check if a var is empty
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, vals) if v!=""}
j = json.dumps(d, indent=2)
print(j)


# {
#   "id": 123,
#   "weight": 40,
#   "depth": 5
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension to loop through the dictionary, and create a new dictionary that only has the non-empty elements.

And use the `json` module to convert to/from JSON.

```
import json

old_dict = json.loads(old_json)
new_dict = {key: value for key, value in old_dict.items() if len(str(value)) > 0}
new_json = json.dumps(new_dict)
```